# How to adjust Devexpress grid width dynamically?

Tags: html-table, devexpress, imagebutton, aspxgridview

1. I have a table with 3 tds, 1st td with 1% width and a image button control(Pin image) in it. 2nd with 98% and DevExpress GridView in it and the 3rd is also 1% width and a image button control.
2. When the user clicks on the Pin image, I do change Grid's Td width to 79% but the Grid's width do not resize accordingly
   until I re-size any column in the grid.
3. After manually resizing a column the grid is adjusted to the TD's width.
4. I do not want to manually do that action instead it should be done programmatically while I click image button control which is in other TD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling [ASPxClientGridView.AdjustControls](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientControl_AdjustControlstopic) after changing Td width.

Comment: How to use this method (ASPxClientGridView.AdjustControls) ?

Comment: Can I have any example for that method Calling??

Comment: Set grid ClientInstanceName attribute to some value, for instance grid1. Then call grid1.AdjustControls().

Answer (score 2):

Set the width of the grid at client side as per the td width and use the columns width in %age by using the `Datarowtemplate`.

```
myGrid.SetWidth(e.pane.GetClientWidth());
```

check these links.. may help you ..

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B142928.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2381.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q130353.aspx